# C99 designator member outside of aggregate initializer

Tags: c++, gcc

```
struct Foo {
    char a[10];
    int b;
};

static Foo foo = {.a="bla"};
```

Compiling the above code gives the following gcc error:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu++2a test.cpp 

C99 designator ‘a’ outside aggregate initializer
```

I thought that c-string designators in initializer list like these are ok in C++20? What am I missing? I am using gcc version 10.

Comment: Compile with clang/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h6jxqTc6h).

Comment: Seems to work since GCC 11.3, sadly it isn't available in my environment just yet :C

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known bug with GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55227

Unfortunately, you will have to either not use designated initializers or use a different initializer for the array:

```cpp
static Foo foo = {"bla"};
static Foo foo = {.a={'b', 'l', 'a', 0}};

// Or if you can change Foo:
struct Foo {
    std::array<char, 10> a;
    int b;
};
static Foo foo = {.a={"bla"}};
```

---

This appears to have been fixed in GCC 11.3 if you can upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I dealt with `mv my.cpp my.c`

You also can find answer in this link:
https://pcbartists.com/firmware/esp32-firmware/designator-outside-aggregate-initializer-solved/

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    // C code goes here
    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I use `strncpy` (from `<cstring>`), for example:

```cpp
strncpy(foo.str, "hello", sizeof(foo_t::str));
```

It seems to be optimized away, therefore generating the same assembly as normal approach in newer GCC (11.3^) and the same as using Artyer solution (the accepted one) of using `char` array.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/9G7b6PT9b

However, the solution might cause `warning: missing initializer for member 'foo_t::str' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]` if you have the `-Wextra` warnings enable, but you can use `-Wno-missing-field-initializers` to exclude it.

By the way, with `stuct`s like that you always have to remember the space is limited, and in many cases you might want leave trailing zero for string end. Using `strncpy` you can force that by adding:

```cpp
foo.str[sizeof(foo_t::str) - 1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me is to include the extra NULL characters, for a total of size-1, since one NULL is automatic, for example:

```
struct Foo {
    char a[6];
    int b;
};

static constexpr Foo foo = {.a="bla\0\0"};
```